# When is an open submanifold of $\mathbb{S}^n$ simply-connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory

Yesterday, I believe, I proved a statement from algebraic topology without actually having properly read any materials about algebraic topology yet. So now, I just wanted to check if this is true, trivial or a known lemma, because I have been searching for it but didn't find anything. Here is the statement:

If $S$ is a smooth hypersurface on a sphere (a closed submanifold, without boundary, of codimension 1), then it is orientable. Further, if $S$ is connected, then its complement consists of two connected components, call them $X$ and $Y$. Further, if $S$ is simply-connected, then $X$ and $Y$ are both simply-connected too.

**Some background**
Initially, I was attempting to prove that the volume bounded by an immersion of $\mathbb{S}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is homeomorphic to a 3-ball and I knew it would be a bit too hard, so for starters I tried proving that it is at least simply-connected. I realized that this still includes some dependency on homotopy groups (the fundamental group) and I know none of that topology. But then I realized that there is another statement which does not depend on simple-connectedness (of neither the surface nor the bounded volume) but is potent enough to carry the property of simple-connectedness down from the boundary to the volume. In fact, it works for any surface.
That another statement is this:

If $S$ is a smooth, compact hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (a compact submanifold, without boundary, of codimension 1), then it is orientable. Further, if $S$ is connected, then its complement consists of two connected components, call them $X$ and $Y$; and exactly one of them is bounded, say $X$. For any $x\in X$, the space of all paths (a path is a continuous mapping from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$) which begin at $x$, end at $S$ and are inside $X$ between the ends is connected (every two such paths are homotopy equivalent within the space of such paths).

Comment: @freakish Sorry, let me add some details.

Comment: @freakish Sorry, I think I was vague again... please let me fix it one more time. I do have problems with being precise when I talk about manifolds... idk why. basically, I meant that $S$ is closed on the sphere. The path you constructed would either not be closed or would have a boundary as a manifold.

Comment: Ahh, "closed" submanifold. In the sense of "compact"?

Comment: @freakish Yes! exaclty

Comment: Ok, so this is very similar to general [Schoenflies problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem#Generalizations), which itself is a variant of [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem). There are of course differences, you are only interested in being simply connected.

Comment: @freakish Oof, I really don't think it is that strong. I really insisted on trying to prove this lemma because I thought of another lemma (which is used to prove the one in the question), which does not include any algebraic-topology language, but can prove this lemma which does say something about algebraic topology. I thought it would be great for me to understand some basic ideas from algebraic topology. I might add that other lemma in the question if you want.

Comment: Have you tried using Van Kampen?

Comment: @MikhailKatz I would if I were skilled enough for it. As of now, I barely understand the statement of Van Kampen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is an answer to an earlier version of the title].  The claim is incorrect.  For example, take the $n$-torus $T^n$ and drill out a small hole.  You get a manifold with simply-connected boundary $S^{n-1}$ but the manifold itself is not simply-connected.

By van Kampen, since $S$ is simply-connected, the fundamental group of $S^n$ would be the free product of the fundamental groups of $X$ and $Y$.  Since $\pi_1(S^n)$ is trivial for $n\geq2$, it follows the same for $X$ and $Y$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93Van_Kampen_theorem

Comment: How is a torus a subset of a sphere? I said that $S$ is a hypersurface on a **sphere**. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: You title speaks of a general $M$.  You may want to clarify the title of your question.

Comment: I agree, but I couldn't think of one that is short enough. Can you please give a suggestion?

Comment: How about "When is an open submanifold of $S^n$ simply-connected"?

Comment: Okay, yes. I will put that. Thanks

Comment: I see it well now. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how exactly you apply van Kampen here. It requires two open subsets that cover space and have path connected intersection. That doesn't seem to be satisfied here.

Comment: @freakish, since everything is smooth, we can take small neighborhoods of $X$ and $Y$ in $S^n$, whose intersection will have the homotopy type of $S$.

Comment: @MikhailKatz $X$ and $Y$ already are open (as components of complement of compact subset). But they don't cover whole sphere and have empty intersection. So you claim you can enlarge them in such a way that: (1) they will cover whole sphere, (2) extensions won't change their fundamental group and (3) their intersection will be simply connected. How exactly?

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is small enough, their $\epsilon$-neighborhoods will intersect in a tubular neighborhood of $S$ which has the homotopy type of $S$ itself.  @freakish

Comment: @MikhailKatz That is not true. Take sphere $S^2$ and upper and lower hemisphere, induced by the equator. Their "$\epsilon$ intersection" is the thick equator, homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, not simply connected.

Comment: @freakish, the OP's hypothesis is that $S$ is simply connected.